# Using a Custom header Button to modify a section in tableview?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to give the ability to delete or add a section to the table view.
I created a custom header view in nib and added a label and 2 buttons to it.
The problem is, i can't connect the dots in deleting or adding a section.
This is my code so far:

```
//Setup Header
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let header = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: headerID) as! CustomHeader
    //Configure header...
    header.addBtn.addTarget(self, action:Selector(("add")), for: .touchUpInside)
    header.addBtn.tag = section

    switch section {
    case 0:
        header.sectionLBL.text = "Detail 1"
    case 1:
        header.sectionLBL.text = "Detail 2"
    default:
        break
    }
    return header
}

@IBAction func addButton(sender: UIButton) {
    //Add section code here...
}

@IBAction func delete(sender:UIButton){
    //delete section code here...
}
```

I was also trying to figure out how i would get the commit style to work with the buttons:

```
    //Setup Editing Style for table view
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(true)


    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
//Editing styles for deletion or insertion...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can connect storyboard scenes or NIBs only to their belonging class.

1) Add a protocol to CustomHeader class and assure the class is assigned to the NIB:

```
protocol CustomHeaderButtonPressDelegate {
    func didPressAdd()
    func didPressDelete()
}

class CustomHeader: UIView {
    var delegate:CustomHeaderButtonPressDelegate?
    @IBAction func addButton(sender: UIButton) {
        delegate?.didPressAdd()
    }

    @IBAction func delete(sender:UIButton){
        delegate?.didPressDelete()
    }
}
```

2) Assign he NIB to the new class in IBs Inspector

[image]

Change "Class" from `UIView` to `CustomHeader`.

3) Connect your button targets to `CustomHeader`s `IBAction`s

4) Set the delegate programatically

```
class YourClass: UITableViewController, CustomHeaderButtonPressDelegate {
...
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let header = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: headerID) as! CustomHeader
    header.delegate = self
...
}
...
func didPressAdd() {
    //handlePress
}
func didPressDelete() {
//handlePress
}
```